# Cyrillic input output, c++

Tags: c++, cyrillic

Still in learning process.
I have made a small program that will :

1. Make a file with users inputs
2. Read the file
3. Fill struct from file, sort and than make a new file "name sorted.txt"

those are my 3 cases. Problem is occurring when I put the Cyrillic text on and try to fill the struct, sort and make a new file.(using case 3:...). Struct is not filling, if I did my test right.
But it's making and reading file correctly (case 1,2)

Program is doing everything right if I only use Latin alphabet. My code if below any help is welcome...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <fstream>
#include "string"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<clocale>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

#define  MAX 10000// max number of students per list

//void sortStruct(); sorting structure
//void swap(studentStruct , studentStruct ); helping with sort function
//void readFile (string );reading a .txt file (ex. Saved list)
//void printStruct(); printing the struct
//void fillStruct(string ); filling a struct from a chosen file, helpin with a sort
//void calculateGrade(ofstream , int ); calcuating average grade, under witch we sort
//void writeToFile(ofstream , string ,float ); writing to a .txt file
//void printMenu(); printing a menu to chose from

//for sorting the list
struct studentStruct{
string name;
float grade;
}student[MAX];


static void printMenu()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout<<"MENU"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Добавить новые записи в файл или создать новый файл"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Распечатайте файл на терминал"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Сделать отсортированный версию текстового файла"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Bыход"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Выберите (цифры) :   ";
}
inline bool exists_test (const std::string& name) {
    ifstream f(name.c_str());
    if (f.good()) {
        f.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        f.close();
        return false;
    }   
}
void writeToFile(ofstream &outputFile, string name,float grade)
{   

    outputFile<<name<<" "<<grade<<endl;

cout << "Готово!\n";
}

void calculateGrade(ofstream &outputFile, int numProf)
{
    float sum;
    string name,last;

    cout<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Введите имя студента : ";
    cin.sync();
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<numProf;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Введите "<<i+1<<". оценку (цифры) : ";
        cin>>sum;
        sum+=sum;
    }
    float grade=sum/numProf; 

    writeToFile(outputFile, name,grade);
}

static void fillStruct(string FileName)
{
    ifstream rdFile;    //Input Object
    bool i;
    i=exists_test(FileName);
    if(i=true)cout<<"IMA";
    rdFile.open(FileName);

    for(int i=0; i<MAX;i++)
    {
        rdFile>>student[i].name;
        rdFile>>student[i].grade;
    }

    rdFile.close();

}
static void printStruct()
{
for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        if(student[i].grade!=0)
        cout<<student[i].name<<" "<<student[i].grade<<endl;}
cout<<"Готово!"<<endl;
}


static void readFile (string FileName)
{
    ifstream rdFile;    //Input Object
    rdFile.open(FileName);
    cout<<endl;
    string n;
    if (!rdFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open...";exit(1);
    }
    else  
    {   
        while (rdFile && getline(rdFile, n))
        {
            if (n.length() == 0)continue;
            cout<<n<<endl;
        }
    }
    rdFile.close();
    cout<<endl<<"Готово!"<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}


void swap(studentStruct &x, studentStruct & y)
{
    studentStruct temp;
    temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

static void sortStruct()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < MAX-i; j++)
        {
            if (student[j].grade < student[j+1].grade)
              {
                  swap(student[j].grade, student[j+1].grade);
                  swap(student[j].name, student[j+1].name);
          }
        }    
       }
}

static void writeStructToFile(string outputFile)
{
    ofstream rdFile;
    rdFile.open(outputFile);
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        if(student[i].grade!=0)
        {
            rdFile<<student[i].name<<" "<<student[i].grade<<endl;
        }
    }
    rdFile.close();

    cout<<"Готово!"<<endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool check;
    int flag=0,numProf,newEntreies;
    string FileName,tempName,n;
    ofstream outputFile;
    ifstream nnn;
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    do 
    {
        system("CLS");
        printMenu();
        cin>>flag;

        //while(flag!=1||flag!=2||flag!=3||flag!=4){
            //system("CLS");        
            //printMenu();
            //cin>>flag;}

        switch(flag)
        {
        case 1 : 
            if(FileName=="exit") {cout<<"Program will exit now..."<<endl; flag=-2;break;}
            else if(FileName=="menu")break;
            cout<<"Выберите имя для нового текстового файла (буквы и цифры):  ";
            cin.sync();
            getline(cin,FileName);
            cout<<"Введите число профессоров (цифры):  ";
            cin>>numProf;
            cout<<"Введите число студентов (цифры) :  ";
            cin>>newEntreies;
            tempName=FileName+".txt";
            check=exists_test(tempName);
            if(check==true)
                outputFile.open(tempName, std::ios_base::app); 
            else
                outputFile.open(tempName);
            if(outputFile.fail()) 
            { //if opening fails then end program
                 cout << "Input file opening failed." << endl;
                 exit(1);
            } //exit function from cstdlib library
            system("CLS");
            for(int i=0; i<newEntreies;i++)
            {
                cout<<FileName<<" "<<numProf<<" "<<newEntreies<<endl<<endl;
                cout<<"Добавление "<<i+1<<". студента...";
                calculateGrade(outputFile,numProf);
                system("CLS");
            }
                outputFile.close();
                cout<<"Нажмите любую клавишу для продолжения..."<<endl;
            break;
        case 2 :
            if(FileName=="exit") {cout<<"Program will exit now..."<<endl;flag=-2;break;}
            else if(FileName=="menu")break;
            cout<<"Введите имя файла:  ";
            cin.sync();
            getline(cin,FileName);
            system("cls");
            cout<<"Чтение из файла "<<FileName<<".txt"<<endl;

            tempName=FileName+".txt";
            readFile(tempName);
            cout<<"Нажмите любую клавишу для продолжения..."<<endl;
            break;
        case 3 : 
            if(FileName=="exit") {flag=-2;break;}
            else if(FileName=="menu")break;
            system("CLS");
            cout<<endl<<"Изготовление отсортированного файла..."<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Выберите файл .txt(буквы и цифры): ";
            cin.sync();
            getline(cin,FileName);
            tempName=FileName+" SORTED.txt";
            fillStruct(FileName+".txt");
            sortStruct();
            writeStructToFile(tempName);
            cout<<endl<<endl<<"Отсортировано версия "<<FileName<<" Готово!"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Нажмите любую клавишу для продолжения..."<<endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            break;
        case 4: cout<< "Program will exit now..."<<endl; flag=-2;break;
        default :cout<<"Program will exit now..."<<endl;flag=-2;break;

        }

    }while(flag!=-2);

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. You need to provide a *small* example that demonstrates the problem. 2. `std::string`, being based on `char`, is only intended to hold ASCII text. You need `std::wstring`.

Comment: `wstring` is a good step forwards, but the Windows console is notoriously tricky to use with Unicode.

Comment: @dandan78 russian in windows is in ASCII, so he should be fine

Comment: You need to be more specific, what do you mean by "Struct is not filling".

Comment: You program cannot do everything right with Latin alphabet either, at least your sorting is broken - you swap grades instead of whole structures

Comment: when I use fillStruct(), to fill my struct from a .txt file, so i can sort it and make a sorted .txt file and then try to printStruct() I get a black screen and also if I try to sort it and make a sorted .txt file he is just blank.

Comment: your `fillStruct()` tries to read 10000 records unconditionally, why you do not use the same pattern as in `readFile()`?

Comment: @Slava you are right I am just sorting grade ... need to fix that

Comment: @user3350597 yet another example why `using namespace std;` is evil

Comment: @Slava that just me trying to write differently...it's a learning process

Comment: @Slava yes i know but It's a bit faster then every time std::cout,cin,etc

Comment: Start with an 8 line program, reading a string then writing it back. Can you do that correctly?

Comment: @user3350597 considering time you spent on debugging your "saving" on not typing `std::cout` is an illusion.

Comment: @n.m yes i can do that, I have functions that are doing that. I am getting the both of my .txt files filled correctly, opened and closed, and when I am not using the Cyrillic alphabet everything is working. It is probably written badly, but I am Practising

Comment: @Slava i know my professor is saying the same thing...I'll pay  more attention to it

Comment: @Slava: "Russian in Windows is in ASCII" -- that line makes *no* sense whatsoever. ASCII is a 7-bit encoding that most definitely does *not* include cyrillics.

Comment: "when I am not using the Cyrillic alphabet" and the point of it would be? The idea is to check what you can do **with** the Cyrillic alphabet, not without it. Does your 8 line program work with Cyrillic characters?

Comment: @DevSolar that's matter of terminology. Let's say it is ASCII extension, which fits in 8bits, so works with `std::string`

Comment: @n.m yes it does i will edit my code

Comment: @Slava: Terminology is **important** when talking about encodings. "ASCII extension that fits in 8 bits" could still be ISO-8859-5, KOI-8R, KOI-8U or something else still. And you really expect the compiler to auto-detect which the OP's source happens to be?

Comment: @DevSolar MS Windows uses (or used until unicode) 2 encodings for cyrillic, CP866  which came from DOS time (which is still used on Windows console by default) and CP1251 for native Windows applications. KOI-8 is mostly used on *nix platforms. Cyrillic is a pretty big mess on IBM PC.

Answer (score 1):

Not looking at your example code much -- too long, too poorly formatted, too badly (not at all) commented.

- What encoding is your source file in? UTF-8? (Which I would strongly suggest, unless you go all the way and use ASCII-7 with escapes.) Or is it ISO-8859-5? Koi-8r? Something else entirely?
- *Did you tell your compiler that?*

Only a very basic instruction set (basically ASCII-7 without `$`, `@` and the backtick) is actually defined by the standard. Anything beyond that is interpreted by the compiler *in an implementation-defined manner*. Either you need to explicitly agree with your compiler about your source encoding, or you need to use hex / oct escapes to keep your source ASCII-7 and enforce a specific encoding manually.

Once you got your literals right for your *compile time* environment, you need your *runtime environment* to agree on things:

- Your terminal needs to have a font with the appropriate cyrillic glyphs.
- As you're using `std::cout`, you should be setting something like `setlocale( LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8" )` or any other UTF-8 locale, if supported by your system (and assuming your literals use that encoding). "Russian" is unlikely to cut it as a locale...

All that being said, **std::string and UTF-8 are a fragile mix**. It's too easy to forget that `length()` doesn't give the number of glyphs, `substr()` might result in invalid byte sequences, `toupper()` doesn't really work for everything, and many other traps like that. I recommend [ICU](http://icu-project.org), which provides a `icu::UnicodeString` that "knows" about all these things.

Comment: "All that being said, std::string and UTF-8 are a fragile mix." I am pretty sure he does not use UTF-8.

Comment: @Slava: All for the worse, because UTF-8 and UTF-16 are basically [the only sane choices](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) today.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately cyrillic encodings have pretty long and pretty messy history on IBM PC and habits die hard.

Comment: @Slava: That's why I try to stamp down on those old habits, and don't accept "8 bit works for me"-approaches.

Comment: @Slava Not that much messier than Chinese or Japanese or Hebrew or Arabic or Thai or whatever.